# iOS CGContextRef Draw Stroke Color and Border Text on UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage, cgcontextref

I'm trying to implement draw stroke text with color and border on UIImage but I can't get the solution.

I have used this [THLabel](https://github.com/MuscleRumble/THLabel) for stroke and border of text and it works fine but only when I copy that code into draw image so at that time it's working for me.

Please see the screen shot for the same. Any suggestions?

**Draw Text on UIImage Method :**

```
- (UIImage *) drawText:(NSString*)text
          inImage:(UIImage*)image
          atPoint:(NSString *)location{

CGFloat fontSize = image.size.width*3/30.0;

NSString *fontName = @"Arial";

int w = image.size.width;
int h = image.size.height;
UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];

int textFrameY = 25;
int textFrameX = 5;
CGSize aSize = [text sizeWithFont:font];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(textFrameX,textFrameY, 80, 30);

CGSize lSize = [location sizeWithFont:font];
CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(image.size.width-lSize.width-fontSize-textFrameX, h-(fontSize*3)-textFrameY, w, h);

[[UIColor blackColor] set];
CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect1);
CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];

[text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withFont:font];
[location drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect1) withFont:font];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;}
```

**THLabel code for stroke color and border for text method:**

```
// Demonstrate stroke.
self.label3.strokeColor = kStrokeColor;
self.label3.strokeSize = kStrokeSize;
```

[image]